# after_create file saving callback resulting in intermittent error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

In my `user` model, I have an `after_create` callback that looks like this:

```
def set_default_profile_image
  file = Tempfile.new([self.initials, ".jpg"])
  file.binmode
  file.write(Avatarly.generate_avatar(self.full_name, format: "jpg", size: 300))
  begin
    self.profile_image = File.open(file.path)
  ensure
    file.close
    file.unlink
  end
  self.save
end
```

(`self.initials` is simply a utility method that returns the user's initials, so that e.g. my profile image would be "HB.jpg".)

If I call the method directly on an existing user, it works maybe 80% of the time. The other times, it gives me an error message so long I can't reproduce it here (I can't even scroll back far enough in tmux to see the start of it). The error message (or what I can see of it, anyway) comprises a list of MIME types, followed by this bit:

```
content type discovered from file command: application/x-empty. See documentation to allow this combination.
```

If I create a new user, the callback results in the same error message 100% of the time.

My method uses the [Avatarly](https://github.com/lucek/avatarly) gem to generate placeholder avatars; the gem yields them in blob form, hence the creation of a `Tempfile` to write to.

I can't understand why the above error would occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in [an issue on Paperclip's github](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1899). I don't really understand the causes very well, but it seems that this is a filesystem issue, where the `Tempfile` is not yet persisted to disk by the time it gets read into the model.

The solution is to do absolutely anything to the `Tempfile` before assigning it; `file.read` works just fine.

```
def set_default_profile_image
  file = Tempfile.new([self.initials, ".jpg"])
  file.binmode
  file.write(Avatarly.generate_avatar(self.full_name, format: "jpg", size: 300))
  file.read # <-- this fixes the issue
  begin
    self.profile_image = File.open(file.path)
  ensure
    file.close
    file.unlink
  end
  self.save
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `full_name` has a valid return value and try moving your `save` call into the `begin` section. You may be racing against a save and the tempfile being removed/unlink.

Comment: I can confirm `full_name` returns correctly, but the other part you mentioned sounds promising. I'll let you know tomorrow. :P

Comment: Tried moving the `save` call into `begin` - no dice.

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect happens when you do this?

```
self.profile_image = File.open(file.path)
```

Without a block, this is the same as:

```
self.profile_image = File.new(file.path)
```

They both return a file object.  Is profile_image in the database?  I'm pretty sure it is going to be mad that you sent a File object to be persisted.  If you want the data from that file in the database, do something like:

```
self.profile_image = File.open(file.path).read
```

If you want to save the tempfile's path:

```
self.profile_image = File.path(file.path)
```

If you are using the path remember that you are saving a tempfile, and the file will not last very long!

Comment: I'm using `paperclip` for storing files in the db, but admittedly I'm not 100% on how it works. I can say however that when I don't get the error described above, the code does work as expected - the file gets uploaded and displays correctly when accessed.